# Download files with extension .txt or wildcard from Amazon S3 using .net sdk?

Tags: vb.net, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

Is there a way to download all the files with specific extension (e.g. `*.txt`) OR wildcard string (`1234 *.*`) from a folder from Amazon S3 using .Net SDK in one go rather then looping through the list of files.

Answer (score 3):

You can't make one call to download all files of a certain pattern but you can use the pattern in the list object call and then download the individual files.  Using the S3DirectoryInfo from the Amazon.S3.IO namespace can simplify this.

```
S3DirectoryInfo info = new S3DirectoryInfo(s3Client, bucketName);
foreach (var file in info.GetFiles("*.jpg", SearchOption.AllDirectories))
{
    var localPath = Path.Combine(@"C:\Temp\download", file.FullName.Substring(bucketName.Length + 2));
    Console.WriteLine("Downloading: {0}", localPath);
    file.CopyToLocal(localPath);
}
```